# Fortran optimization using Blas or not

Tags: optimization, fortran, blas

I have the following Fortran code

```
DO ir = 1, N
     cfac = exp( ci*B ) / dble( degen(ir) )
     C(:,:) = C(:,:) + cfac*D(:,:, ir )
ENDDO
```

This loop take 14.00s with gcc -02.

I would like to optimize it. I tried with the BLAS
routine that does matrix-vector multiplication:

```
DO ir = 1, N
   cfac(ir) = exp( ci*B ) / dble( degen(ir) )
ENDDO

DO j = 1, M
  CALL zgemv ('n', M, N, cone, D(j,:,:), M,cfac(:),1,czero, C(j,:), 1 )
ENDDO
```

Turns out, I get the same result but in ... 17.67s.

Why is it slower and how can I improve the code (without changing compiler option)?

Thank you,

Samuel

Comment: How large are N and M? it is well possible that those BLAS routines just can't help you at all and you are just adding overhead. Which BLAS implementation did you try? The compilers are good to optimizing the loops themselves, I don't use GEMV anywhere.

Comment: You're also probably getting copy in/copy out when you call zgemv as the elements you want to access in C and D are not contiguous in memory. The copy of D in particular will probably kill your performance. Oh, and these are BLAS routines - this question has nothing to do with ScaLAPACK which while related is very different to BLAS.

Comment: Thank you Ian !
I've changed the title to Blas. Do you think it is possible to improve the performance by modifying the code (using or not Blas)? Typically N is large and M not so much. I timed the two loops. First one is 4sec and second one is 13.67 sec, resulting in 17.67s.

Comment: I don't think so. But you still did not reply what are the values of N and M. It would be useful to see the output of `-fdump-tree-optimized` if you use gfortran. Also, try `-fopt-info` to find out what kind of optimizations (e.g., vectorization) the compiler does. You may want to try -O2 which does some loop unrolling differently, it may help but also harm. Overall, I am quite sceptical, if the compiler already vectorizes it, there won't be much space for improvement.

Comment: Also, using `C(:,:)` is discouraged and it may confuse the optimizer, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this

Comment: Hello Vladimir, The dim of N and M change depending on the problem but N is typically around 1000+ and M around 50.
I have try to put C(1:M,1:M) but it does not help.

Comment: @sponce I believe the suggestion was to use just `C` and discard the `(:,:)`, which specifies an array section (the whole array in your case). (See the blog post.)

Comment: @VladimirF: IDK about fortran, but for C `-funroll-loops` isn't part of gcc's `-O2` or `-O3`.  It is part of `-fprofile-use`.  Autovectorization usually only happens at `-O3`.  So for the OP, `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -funroll-loops` might be a good choice.  (Leave out `-ffast-math` / `-Ofast` if you need rounding to happen in source-code order, and/or to handle infinities and NaN the way the source would.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right, I confused several different aspects. Here they suggest to limit the unrolling by `--param max-unroll-times=2` or 4 https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.fortran/dcGPDgo1-w0/wBHHf7o-BAAJ

Comment: @VladimirF: For loops with a loop-carried dependency (e.g. find max value in an array, or dot product, or sum of an array), it helps to use multiple accumulators in the source code, with some source-level unrolling.  This hides the latency of the FP ops, by having 4 independent operations in flight.  (After the loop, add your four accumulators together.)  Compiler unrolling unfortunately doesn't use multiple accumulators (beyond the vector width when autovectorizing: i.e. there will be only one vector accumulator in an array-sum loop)).  IDK if any compilers do use multiple accumulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to improve it is the following

```
DO ir = 1, N
     cfac = exp( ci*B ) / dble( degen(ir) )
     CALL zaxpy(M**2,cfac, D(1,1, ir ),1, C (1,1),1)
ENDDO
```

With this I go roughly from 15s to 13s.